# Arrange multiple ggplots, but avoid squishing due to axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, gtable, cowplot

I've been using cowplot::plot_grid to arrange multiple ggplot figures, which has been working great in general.  However, I've now run into a problem where I want to include the x axis labels on just the bottom plot, but it ends up squishing all the plots (with align = "vh") or the lowest plot (with align = "v") in the column.

Is there any way to perhaps extract the x-axis label grob, and add that as a another plot in plot_grid (perhaps similar to https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/vignettes/shared_legends.Rmd for legends)?  Or another approach?

Thanks for any thoughts!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

a = data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rep(c("laskjdflsakjd", "cknmlokfjoweijojf"), 50))
b = data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rep(c("laskjdflsakjd", "cknmlokfjoweijojf"), 50))
c = data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rep(c("laskjdflsakjd", "cknmlokfjoweijojf"), 50))

aplot = ggplot(a, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
bplot = ggplot(b, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
cplot = ggplot(c, aes(x=b, y=a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))

plot_grid(aplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank()),
        bplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank()),
        cplot, ncol = 1, align = "vh")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the relative heights directly, though it may take a fair bit of tinkering (and will change anytime your plot size changes). In addition, for a single column, you should just be able to use `align = "v"` -- the "h" option is trying to line up the bottoms of the plots as well (hence why it is re-adding the space for the axis labels).

This worked reasonably well for me:

```
plot_grid(aplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
          , bplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
          , cplot
          , ncol = 1
          , align = "v"
          , rel_heights = c(0.5,0.5,1)
          )
```

[image]

In addition, here is the obligatory suggestion to consider `facet_wrap` though your actual use case presumably does not allow it.

Finally, I have in the past tried to extract the axes to do what you suggested: it did not go well. I had immense problems getting them to line up correctly and eventually abandoned the attempt to return to setting `rel_heights`

For completeness, here is an approach using `facet_wrap` (using `bind_rows` from `dplyr`):

```
df <-
  bind_rows(a = a, b = b, c = c
            , .id = "df")

ggplot(df, aes(x=b, y=a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~df, ncol = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark - I've also reverted to the rel_heights fix for now, but was hoping to find a more robust solution at some point...

Comment: Is there a reason that `facet_wrap` won't work? That may be the more robust solution (but only works if the plots are all the same)

Comment: Yeah, facet_wrap doesn't line up the axes well.  Even if they're the "same" plot, if the y scales differ, for example, such that one goes to 10 and the other to 100, the axes won't line up.  Furthermore, in reality, i'm mixing some plots (made them the same for the reproducible example).  Cowplot does a great job lining things up, but this x-axis issue is a pain.  I imagine there must be a way to do this via grobs and such, but I really don't understand all the details.  Perhaps there's not...